# Filling an array passed as a parameter with objects

Tags: c++, arrays, object, parameter-passing

I have a function similar to this:

```
void foo(obj ary[], int arysize) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arysize; i++)
         ary[i] = obj(i, "abc");
}
```

And I call it like this:

```
obj array[5];
foo(array, 5);
```

It's supposed to populate the array with my objects. However, when it returns, the objects are garbage. It works with value types like `int` and stuff, so I think it's something to do with the object I create being local in scope so it gets destroyed when the function returns. I would like to be able to do this without using dynamically allocated objects with `new`. How can I do this?

Comment: Does your obj class has memory allocation in its constructor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should work fine.   I'd look into the assignment operator for your class.

Comment: Wow how stupid of me. The assignment operator was changing the attributes of the object but not copying the data over. Thanks.